# change colors of `hg commit --interactive`

Tags: terminal, mercurial

The colors used by `hg commit --interactive` are unreadable in my terminal.
Is there a way to choose the colors used in this command in a configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the colors in the curses UIs are not configurable.

Most terminals let you switch the colors that they use for the base 16 colors, and the curses UI only uses those colors, so you can probably adjust the colors in your terminal's settings. This has the benefit that it fixes the issue in other programs besides Mercurial as well.